# GNU RISC-V Make Trying to Access File in Directory it just Created

Tags: cmake, gnu

I'm trying to run xv6-riscv. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, so I needed to build the gnu-riscv-toolchain. Following [these](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2019/tools.html) instructions, I ran `sudo make`. Eventually, make produced the following output:

```
rm -rf stamps/build-newlib build-newlib
mkdir build-newlib
cd build-newlib && /mnt/c/Users/vrait/Documents/Code/OperatingSystems/riscv-gnu-toolchain/newlib/configure \
        --target=riscv64-unknown-elf \
         \
        --prefix=/usr/local \
        --enable-newlib-io-long-double \
        --enable-newlib-io-long-long \
        --enable-newlib-io-c99-formats \
        --enable-newlib-register-fini \
        CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="-O2 -D_POSIX_MODE -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -mcmodel=medlow" \
        CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="-O2 -D_POSIX_MODE -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -mcmodel=medlow"
/bin/sh: 1: /mnt/c/Users/vrait/Documents/Code/OperatingSystems/riscv-gnu-toolchain/newlib/configure: not found
make: *** [Makefile:622: stamps/build-newlib] Error 127
```

Line 622 is the Makefile line that's producing the error:

```
rm -rf $@ $(notdir $@)
mkdir $(notdir $@)
cd $(notdir $@) && $</configure \
    # some args
```

I don't have much experience with CMake, but my understanding is that this code deletes `notdir`, creates a new `notdir` directory, moves into it, and then tries to run `/configure` with some arguments. I'm confused as to how this could work: you're trying to access a file in an empty directory you just created. How could there ever be a file there for you to access?

Changing `/configure` to `/../configure` allows me to hack past this error (there is a configure file in the root directory of the gnu-riscv-toolchain that I assume this causes the program to access), but Make stalls suddenly after outputting the following (no error message, it just stops producing output):

```
cd build-binutils-newlib && CC_FOR_TARGET=riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc /mnt/c/Users/vrait/Documents/Code/OperatingSystems/riscv-gnu-toolchain/newlib/../binutils/configure \
    # some args
```

Which I assume is caused somehow by the change of `/configure` to `/../configure`.

How could the `rm`, `mkdir`, `cd`, `/configure` sequence work without always trying to access a file that doesn't exist? Also, what would be the correct approach to fixing the `not found` error?

Comment: `cmake` doesn't seem to be involved here - just `make`. In a Makefile, the automatic variable `$<` refers to the first prerequisite of the current rule - so (as you can see from your first fragment) it's not trying to run `./configure`, it's trying to run `/mnt/c/Users/vrait/Documents/Code/OperatingSystems/riscv-gnu-toolchain/newlib/configure` . My *guess* is that it the `not found` error is because you're trying to do this on a Windows filesystem (at `/mnt/c`) that doesn't understand Linux executable permissions.

Comment: okay thank you! I am running make from within the ubuntu terminal, and it seemed to have no problem up to this point. How would it be using the windows filesystem?

Comment: The path `/mnt/c/Users/vrait/Documents/Code/OperatingSystems/` suggests like you are using WSL and have downloaded the toolchain source to your Windows `Documents` directory

Comment: Ah okay. I tried downloading and building it in /home/vraiti and it worked. Thanks!